# Save/update/delete based on object existense

Tags: javascript, spring, hibernate, leaflet

I am working on leaflet and saving the list of drawn markers in database using ajax call. Here are the steps :-

- Draw all the markers on map.
- Create a json array and pass to spring controller and save the details in database.

Now if I click on save button again ,the same marker's details get saved in database again and again.

**Requirement :**

I want the following :-
 - Only new markers should be saved as new row in database.
 - If any marker is deleted (Out of all the saved ones), the deleted one should be deleted from database.
 - If any new marker is added in the list, a new row should be saved.

I am using spring and hibernate. Can anyone suggest me how can I handle these scenarios?

**This is my Entity class :-**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "markers")
public class Markers{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "layer")
    private Layer layer;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "markerDetail", nullable = false)
    private MarkerDetail markerDetailId;

    @Column(name = "markerName")
    private String markerName;

    @Column(name = "latitude")
    private Double latitude;

    @Column(name = "longitude")
    private Double longitude;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MapId")
    private Map map;
/*This is the mapID on which the markers exists*/
}
```

And this is how I am saving the list of markers by converting them into object of java :-

```
for(MarkerVO marker : markers){
        markerList.add(marker);
    }
    markerDAO.saveDevices(markerList);
```

Any suggestions if this can be handled by override equals() and hashcode() in entity class or anything like that ?

Comment: If they are saved in DB, you can always use their uniqueness and maintain them, why do you even need equals and hashcode for that?

Comment: How about this: First delete all markers from the database and then save all items in the json array in the database as new markers?